# VB.NET: Check if List items are equal and have same count

Tags: vb.net, list, generics, comparison

How can I detect whether the items of two given lists are equal?

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer)
list1.AddRange({1, 2, 3})

Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)
list2.AddRange({3, 2, 1})
```

If I compare them using `SequenceEqual` I get `False` because the order of the items is not the same. How can I compare them *without sorting* them first, though?

EDIT: Please take into account that this should respect duplicates, for example `{1, 2, 3, 1}` is not the same as `{1, 2, 3}` (item `1` occurs two times in the first list).

Comment: Loop through one of the lists and check if the other list contains the element. Also check that the lists are the same length.

Comment: Why "without sorting them" first? Sounds like a good choice.

Comment: @SysDragon: sounds good, yes, but what if you want to keep the order in the lists? But this led me to my final implementation, though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Function AreItemsEqual(Of T)(col1 As IEnumerable(Of T), col2 As IEnumerable(Of T)) As Boolean
    ' performance checks
    If col1 Is col2 Then Return True
    If col1 Is Nothing OrElse col2 Is Nothing Then Return False
    If col1.Count <> col2.Count Then Return False
    ' compare their elements
    Dim o1 As IEnumerable(Of T) = col1.OrderBy(Function(i) i)
    Dim o2 As IEnumerable(Of T) = col2.OrderBy(Function(i) i)
    Return o1.SequenceEqual(o2)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
If list1.AreItemsEqual(list2) Then
    ...
```

Comment: Similar approach than mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17787628/284240 However, not very efficient if the collections are large.

Comment: `SequenceEqual` does the same as my `For`-loop, both break as soon as the condition was `False`. However, both are ineficient since both collections must be copied into a new collection and both colllections need to be ordered completely.

Comment: What if both lists are Nothing?

Comment: You're right, the order of the first 2 checks needed to be switched; I updated the function.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know if both lists contain the same items you can use `Enumerable.Except`:

```
Dim bothContainSameItems As Boolean
If list1.Count > list2.Count Then
    bothContainSameItems = Not list1.Except(list2).Any()
Else
    bothContainSameItems = Not list2.Except(list1).Any()
End If
```

or, with the help of [`HashSet(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516.aspx):

```
Dim l1Set = New HashSet(Of Integer)(list1)
Dim l2Set = New HashSet(Of Integer)(list2)
bothContainSameItems = l1Set.SetEquals(l2Set)
```

Note that both approaches will ignore duplicates. So they will return `equal` for:

```
list1.AddRange({1, 1, 2, 3})
list2.AddRange({3, 2, 1, 3})
```

Here's a possible way to also check if all numbers have the same count in both lists:

```
bothContainSameItems = list1.Count = list2.Count
If bothContainSameItems Then
    Dim l1Ordered = list1.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToList()
    Dim l2Ordered = list2.OrderBy(Function(i) i).ToList()
    For i As Int32 = 0 To l1Ordered.Count - 1
        If l1Ordered(i) <> l2Ordered(i) Then
            bothContainSameItems = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Counter-example: `list1={1,1,2,3}`, `list2={1,2,3}`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I've already added a similar example. It depends on the requirement whether or not  he wants to compare sets.

Answer (score 1):

Also working with

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer)
list1.AddRange({1, 2, 3})

Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer)
list2.AddRange({3, 2, 1})

Dim list3 = list1.Union(list2)
if list3.OrderBy(Function(i) i).SequenceEqual(list1.OrderBy(Function(i) i)) then
    Console.WriteLine("Equal")
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal")
end if
```

[IEnumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx)

> Return Value: An IEnumerable(Of T) that contains the elements from both input sequences,
>   excluding duplicates.

Comment: This changes the first list and doesn't take duplicates into account.

Comment: @Johannes I have stated the fact that the union changes the list. And why do you think that doesn't take duplicates into account when the documentation says clearly the opposite? At least check before downvoting

Comment: The documentation clearly says it. Check this example: `{1,2,3}` and `{1,2,3,1}` and vice versa.

Comment: The docs say: `Excluding duplicates' so {1,2,3,4} union {1,2,3,5} returns {1,2,3,4,5}, my error is not writing `list3 = list1.Union(list2)` because the unique list is the return value of union not the first list. However you are right, this is not the correct answer for your question because you still haven't a way to tell if the two lists are different (and counting is not a valid way)

Comment: Yep, but `{1,2,3,1}.Union({1,2,3})` is still `{1,2,3,1}` :)

Comment: `Dim list3 = list1.Union(list2)` and check the contents of list3