# Compare two Lists of Lists of String

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I want to compare two Lists of Lists of String:

```
Dim ListV1 = New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim ListV2 = New List(Of List(Of String))
Dim ListResult = New List(Of List(Of String))

Fil(ListV1)
Fil(ListV2) 
ListResult = ***Compare***( ListV1 ,ListV2 )
```

What code can I use to generate this comparison?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VB.NET: Check if List items are equal and have same count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787538/vb-net-check-if-list-items-are-equal-and-have-same-count)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do with the assumption of compare meaning equivalent values and that the list should contain all of one sublist if there is a discrepancy between sublists.

```
Enum Side
    Left
    Right
End Enum

Function Compare2DLists(list1 As List(Of List(Of String)), list2 As List(Of List(Of String)), takeSide As Side) As List(Of List(Of String))
    Dim newList As New List(Of List(Of String))

    For i = 0 To list1.Count - 1
        Dim areEqual As Boolean = True
        For j = 0 To list1.Count - 1
            If Not list1(i)(j) = list2(i)(j) Then
                areEqual = False

            End If
        Next

        If areEqual = False Then
            Select Case takeSide
                Case Side.Left
                    newList.Add(list1(i))

                Case Side.Right
                    newList.Add(list2(i))
            End Select

        Else
            newList.Add(list1(i))
        End If
    Next

    Return newList

End Function
```

This assumes that list1 is the same size of list2 such that if list1 is 4x4 then list2 is 4x4

Comment: Maybe you should add `Break`s if `areEqual` is false to prevent the loops running till the end.

Comment: What happens if one of the lists (inner or outer) in `list1` is longer than the corresponding list in `list2`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a number of assumptions here, which may be incorrect in your case. You really need to clarify some points about how this comparison should work:

1. Presumably you want to compare the individual values in the lists; if two lists contain the same values in the same position, they should be considered equal, even though they are actually different list objects.
2. Since you chose `List` for both dimensions (and not something like `Hashset`) I assume that order is important -- `{"a","b"}` is not equivalent to `{"b","a"}`.
3. If one `List(Of String)` is longer than the other, the corresponding result list will be as long as the longer list, but filled with `Nothing` values for the difference.
4. From your choice of `List(Of List(Of String))` to store the results, I'm going to assume you want to return the values that are equivalent in the corresponding positions; non-equivalent values will have `Nothing` in the corresponding result.
5. Since you're using VB.NET, I'm assuming you want a case-insensitive comparison.

---

I suggest adding the following two extension methods:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Module ListFunctions
    Public Function MaxLength(Of T)(l1 As List(Of T), l2 As List(Of T)) As T
        Dim l1Length = If(l1?.Count,0)
        Dim l2Length = If(l2?.Count,0)
        Return Math.Max(l1Length, l2Length)
    End Function
    <Extension()> Public Function TryGet(Of T)(l As List(Of T), idx As Integer) As T
        If If(l?.Count, 0) <= idx Then Return Nothing
        Return l(idx)
    End Function
End Module
```

Then, within your code block:

```
Dim listComparer = Function(l1 As List(Of String), l2 As List(Of String))
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, MaxLength(l1,l2)).Select(Function(i)
                Dim s1 = l1.TryGet(i)
                Dim s2 = l2.TryGet(i)
                If s1 = s2 Then Return s1
                Return Nothing
            End Function).ToList
    End Function

Dim listsComparer = Function(ll1 As List(Of List(Of String)), ll2 As List(Of List(Of String)))
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, MaxLength(ll1,ll2)).Select(Function(i)
                Dim l1 = ll1.TryGet(i)
                Dim l2 = ll2.TryGet(i)
                Return listComparer(l1,l2)
            End Function).ToList
    End Function

Dim ListResult = listsComparer(ListV1, ListV2)
```